# Can I store wet coffee beans in the fridge?

Tags: health, ground-coffee, beans, storage

My coffee beans accidentally got wet. Can I store them in the refrigerator for 3 to 4 days? Or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a food safety perspective, three to four days should be fine. For longer periods, simply freeze them. But...

Wet beans will likely clog up your grinder and it’s probably not a good choice, flavor-wise. The wet beans will likely change flavor during the time in the fridge, and most likely not in a good way.

Drying them again would be better. Either place them in a single layer in a well-ventilated area or in a warm oven with the door slightly ajar. You will lose some flavor each way, but that probably can’t be prevented.