# To what temperature do coffee grounds need to be freezed at, after getting wet?

Tags: ground-coffee

As per this question [Can I store wet coffee beans in fridge?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/can-i-store-wet-coffee-beans-in-fridge?newreg=8de5d3ed2f5445f38bc387fcdb97d649) "From a food safety perspective, three to four days should be fine. For longer periods, simply freeze them"

Although the link references to beans, I am more interested in coffee grounds, so not sure if it would still be applicable. To what temperature can I freeze them to prevent mold and how much time is the maximum I can store it ?

Answer (score 1):

The standard refrigerator temperature most official websites assume are around 4C. Yes, there are different temperature zones in home refrigerators, but that’s included in the general recommendation of 3-4 days for “prepared foods” category - which wet coffee grounds would fall into.

Freezer storage below-18 C is “unlimited” from a microbiological perspective - the activity of mold and bacteria is near zero. But over time, the quality of frozen food will suffer. Interestingly, it’s often the fats that still will go rancid, especially if the item isn’t wrapped tightly and oxygen can reach the product. Improper packaging and temperature fluctuations can also create [freezer burn.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezer_burn) As the oils in coffee are an important contributor to flavor, I wouldn’t exceed three months of freezer time, but that’s purely for quality reasons, not due to food safety concerns.

Our sister site [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com) has a [generic Q/A on safe storage times](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer) and a lot of additional information.